# R, deep vs. shallow copies, pass by reference

Tags: r, reference, copy, deep-copy, data.table

I would like to understand the logic R uses when passing arguments to functions, creating copies of variables, etc. with respect to the memory usage.  When does it actually create a copy of the variable vs. just passing a reference to that variable?  In particular the situations I am curious about are:

```
f <- function(x) {x+1}
a <- 1
f(a)
```

Is `a` being passed literally or is a reference to a being passed?

```
x <- 1
y <- x
```

Reference of copy?  When is this not the case?

If someone could explain this to me I would highly appreciate.

Comment: You might find [this](http://cran.at.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Evaluation) section of the R language definition helpful.

Comment: This paper by Morandat and colleagues has an interesting and critical discussion of lazy evaluation of arguments in R: http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/jv/pubs/ecoop12.pdf

Comment: Using `tracemem` on an appropriately compiled R can be helpful for exploration, as can `.Internal(inspect(x))` with an understanding of the `NAM`ED field; my general mantra is 'copy-on-change' so for instance your `y <- x` does not trigger a copy (yet) because there has been no change to the original, the memory pointed to by `x` (and `y`) is `NAMED` such that modification of either will trigger a copy.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When it passes variables, it is always by copy rather than by reference. Sometimes, however, you will not get a copy made until an assignment actually occurs. The real description of the process is pass-by-promise. Take a look at the documentation

```
?force
?delayedAssign
```

One practical implication is that it is very difficult if not impossible to avoid needing at least twice as much RAM as your objects nominally occupy. Modifying a large object will generally require making a temporary copy.

update: 2015: I do (and did) agree with Matt Dowle that his data.table package provides an alternate route to assignment that avoids the copy-duplication problem. If that was the update requested, then I didn't understand it at the time the suggestion was made.

There was a recent change in R 3.2.1 in the evaluation rules for `apply` and `Reduce`. It was SO-announced with reference to the News here: [Returning anonymous functions from lapply - what is going wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742177/returning-anonymous-functions-from-lapply-what-is-going-wrong/29786817#29786817)

And the [interesting paper cited by jhetzel in the comments is now here](http://r.cs.purdue.edu/pub/ecoop12.pdf):

Comment: Enter [`data.table`](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/). See `?copy` in the package. Assignment by reference is possible with the `:=` operator, see `?":="` and the series of `set*` functions. Instead of needing room for 2-3 copies of the entire object, we aim to only need one column's worth of working memory or less.

Answer (score 13):

Late answer but a very important aspect of the language design that don't get enough coverage on the web (or at least the usual sources).

```
x <- c(0,4,2)
lobstr::obj_addr(x)
# [1] "0x7ff25e82b0f8"
y <- x
lobstr::obj_addr(y)
# [1] "0x7ff25e82b0f8"
```

Notice the identical "memory address", i.e. the location in memory where the object is stored. You can thus confirm that `x` and `y` both point to the same identifier.

Hadley Wickham's Advanced R book touch on this:

> **Consider this code**:
>
> `x <- c(1, 2, 3)`
>
> It’s easy to read it as: “create an object named ‘x’,
>   containing the values 1, 2, and 3”. Unfortunately, that’s a
>   simplification that will lead to inaccurate predictions about what R
>   is actually doing behind the scenes. It’s more accurate to say that
>   this code is doing two things:
>
> It’s creating an object, a vector of values, `c(1, 2, 3)`. And it’s
>   binding that object to a name, `x`. In other words, the object, or
>   value, doesn’t have a name; it’s actually the name that has a value.

Note that they are the memory addresses are ephemeral and change with every new R session.

Now here is the important part.

> In R semantics, objects are copied by value. This means that modifying
>   the copy leaves the original object intact. Since copying data in
>   memory is an expensive operation, copies in R are as lazy as possible.
>   They only happen when the new object is actually modified.
>   Source: [R lang documentation][1]

So if we now modify the value of `y` by appending a value to the vector, `y` now points to a different "object". This agrees with what the documentation says regarding a copy operation happening "only when the new object is modified" (lazy). `y` is pointing to a different address than it was previously.

```
y <- c(y, -3)
print(lobstr::obj_addr(y))
# [1] "0x7ff25e825b48"
```

Answer (score 1):

@onlyphantom That's super helpful! And objects can round trip out of a function without being copied also: which was what brought me here:

```
tmp <- function(x, create) {
    if(!create){
        x
    }else{
        "new"
    }
}

x = c(0,4,2)

y = tmp(x, F)
lobstr::obj_addr(x) == lobstr::obj_addr(y) # y points to x!
```

And this works when "replacing" x with itself - no copy!

```
oldAddr = lobstr::obj_addr(x) 
x = tmp(x, F)
lobstr::obj_addr(x) == oldAddr # TRUE!
```

This example from the manual (modified slightly) was also informative about triggering a lazy evaluation

```
tmp = function(x, label = deparse(x), force=TRUE) {
    if(force){
        label
    }
    x <- x + 1
    print(label); return(x)
}
tmp(2)
[1] "2"
[1] 3

tmp(2, force=F)
[1] "3"
[1] 3
```

R version 3.6.3

Comment: Thank you for the insightful examples! Do you know if this copying of an object – say a matrix – also happen when we are using subsets of the object as arguments to a function?