# Does returning from a function create an extra copy?

Tags: r

In the function below:

```
DownloadRawData <- function(fileurl, filename)
{
    download.file(fileurl, destfile=filename)
    dataset = read.csv(filename)
    return(dataset)
}
myDataSet <- downloadRawData(myurl, myname)
```

Are we going to allocate 2 copies of the dataset in memory at the function return, or the assignment will be by reference.

This thread [R, deep vs. shallow copies, pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655287/r-deep-vs-shallow-copies-pass-by-reference) give some hints about it, but it was not that clear to me.

Another similar example would be:

```
f <- function(n)
{
    v <- c(1:n)
    v <- sample(v,n)
    return(v)
}
myV <- f(10000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see how `return()` is internally implemented by taking a look at [src/main/eval.c](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/eval.c) in the R source. It is function `do_return()`, which also calls `eval()`. Only SEXPs are passed around, and these [are pointers](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#SEXPs).

So the answer is, no extra copy of the returned value is being created. It is essentially optimized away.