# Returning anonymous functions from lapply - what is going wrong?

Tags: r, closures, anonymous-function, lapply

When trying to create a list of similar functions using `lapply`, I find that all the functions in the list are identical and equal to what the final element should be.

Consider the following:

```
pow <- function(x,y) x^y
pl <- lapply(1:3,function(y) function(x) pow(x,y))
pl
[[1]]
function (x) 
pow(x, y)
<environment: 0x09ccd5f8>

[[2]]
function (x) 
pow(x, y)
<environment: 0x09ccd6bc>

[[3]]
function (x) 
pow(x, y)
<environment: 0x09ccd780>
```

When you try to evaluate these functions you get identical results:

```
pl[[1]](2)
[1] 8
pl[[2]](2)
[1] 8
pl[[3]](2)
[1] 8
```

What is going on here, and how can I get the result I desire (the correct functions in the list)?

Comment: I am not sure, what your goal is. Maybe `pl <- function(x,y) lapply(y,function(y) pow(x,y)); pl(2,1:3)`?

Comment: These notes by Ross Ihaka (RCore) might be helpful (specifically the part about Lazy Evaluation) www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/downloads/Waikato-WRUG.pdf

Comment: Note that this is no longer true as of R 3.2.0, see my answer below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

R passes [promises](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Promise-objects), not the values themselves.  The promise is forced when it is first evaluated, not when it is passed, and by that time the index has changed if one uses the code in the question.  The code can be written as follows to [force](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/force.html) the promise at the time the outer anonymous function is called and to make it clear to the reader:

```
pl <- lapply(1:3, function(y) { force(y); function(x) pow(x,y) } )
```

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know how this pitfall works. I'll have to keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 8):

This is no longer true as of R 3.2.0!

The corresponding line in the [change log](http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS) reads:

> Higher order functions such as the apply functions and Reduce() now
>   force arguments to the functions they apply in order to eliminate
>   undesirable interactions between lazy evaluation and variable capture
>   in closures.

And indeed:

```
pow <- function(x,y) x^y
pl <- lapply(1:3,function(y) function(x) pow(x,y))
pl[[1]](2)
# [1] 2
pl[[2]](2)
# [1] 4
pl[[3]](2)
# [1] 8
```