# Evaluate elipsis (dots) multiple times, substitute arguments

Tags: r, functional-programming, ellipsis

## Context

I am using in R, the "elipsis" or "dots" that wrap function calls

```
main_function <- function(...)
```

If I want to evaluate once, I do

```
main_function <- function(...) {
    res = list(...)}
```

It works fine

## Problem

```
fun_A <- function(arg_A){
    print(paste("I am A", paste0(round(runif(arg_A, 0,1), 2),collapse = ", ")))
}

fun_B <- function(arg_B){
    print(paste("I am B", paste0(round(runif(arg_B, 1,2), 2),collapse = ", ")))
}
```

Here the result is evaluated once and replicate 3 times :

```
main_fun_wrong <- function(..., times) {
    res = list(...)
    replicate(times, eval(res))
}

main_fun_wrong(fun_A(1), fun_B(2), times = 3)
```

Here it works :

```
main_fun <- function(..., times) {
    calls = match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$`...`
    replicate(times, lapply(1:length(calls), function(num) eval(calls[[num]])), simplify = F)
}

main_fun(fun_A(1),fun_B(2), times = 3)
```

But now if arg_A is an object rather than a value, it will fail finding the arg_A and arg_B in the environment.

```
main_fun_problem <- function(arg_A, arg_B) {
    main_fun(fun_A(arg_A),fun_B(arg_B), times = 3)
}

main_fun_problem(1,2)
```

I got an error :

> Error in fun_A(arg_A) : object 'arg_A' not found

I do not know what R do when it find list(...) the first time in first example but I just want to repeat it multiple times.

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete example?

Comment: @nrussell Thx.I did not provided example but rephrased it to make it more clear

Comment: `replicate(10,  eval(calls))` won't evaluate 10 times, it just replicates 10 times the results from single evaluation

Comment: @jangorecki indeed but the problem remain if I wrap it in a for loop

Comment: you should also make example reproducible, so provided funA and funB

Comment: this cannot be seen from your current example, funA and funB should increment a counter or prints to console

Comment: @jangorecki  example has been added :) Thanks for helping

Comment: @nrussell  example has been added :) Thanks for helping

Comment: you may also read the source of `microbenchmark::microbenchmark` function as it does exactly what you are looking for

Comment: @jangorecki actually replicate does evaluate multiple time in the solution. I may have a look at microbenchmark source eventually. Thanks

Comment: @zakrapovic interesting, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: I think this has more to do with your `lapply` + `<<-` attempt than the ellipsis. If you want to do something iteratively, use a `for` loop...

Comment: @Frank sory I do not understand. the <<- has been used to make a state in the reproductible example and control that it has been evaluated multiple time. But I do not like it much, will change.

Comment: To clarify, I mean: `update_A = function(arg_A) A + arg_A;
A = 0; arg_A = 5; n = 3;
res = numeric(n);
for (i in seq_along(res)) res[[i]] = (A <- update_A(arg_A))
`

Comment: @Frank It was messy I changed example. Hope am done now.

Comment: Ok. `eval(substitute(replicate(times, list(...))))` seems fine to me. This is no big improvement over `replicate(list(whatever), n = 3)`... just saves you from manually writing `list`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, any alternative will be enjoyed.

The things is to substitute the variable by it's value at the moment we call the function.

```
main_fun_solution <- function(arg_A, arg_B) {
    eval(substitute(main_fun(fun_A(arg_A),fun_B(arg_B), times = 3), list("arg_A" =  arg_A, "arg_B" =  arg_B)))
}

main_fun_solution(1,2)
```

NB: list("arg_A" =  arg_A, "arg_B" =  arg_B)` makes my heart bleed (the overall solution actually)

Comment: Just came across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084193/how-to-not-fall-into-rs-lazy-evaluation-trap?rq=1). I will read further, it looks like a good alternative.