# data.table::set interacts with other data.frame

Tags: r, data.table

While trying to replace NA's in a `data.frame` I discover a weird behaviour of `data.table::set()`. I'm not used to the `data.table` syntax, but `set()` is supposed to work for `data.frame` as well.

The following code shows the problem:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(c(1,NA),5,rep=TRUE)))

dt <- as.data.table(data)
dt_red <- dt[-1, -2]

df <- data
df_red <- df[-1, -2]

sum(is.na(data))
sum(is.na(dt))
sum(is.na(dt_red))
sum(is.na(df))
sum(is.na(df_red))

ind <- as.integer(c(2,3))
for (j in ind)
  set(data,which(is.na(data[[j]])),j,0) 

sum(is.na(data))
sum(is.na(dt))
sum(is.na(dt_red))
sum(is.na(df))
sum(is.na(df_red))
```

The function is supposed to replace NA's in column's 2 and 3 from data with 0, which it does. It also replaces the NA's in df, which it really shouldn't. if data is safed as data.table or modified, nothing is changed...

Any ideas?

P.S.
The post is not about how to change the script to make it work (I did that), but to help me realise how `set()` is allowed to change `df`, while only be given `data` to work with?

Comment: `data.table` work with references (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another). If you don't want any modification on `data`, you should use `df <- copy(data)`

Comment: relevant: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Confused-about-NAMED-td4103326.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655287/r-deep-vs-shallow-copies-pass-by-reference. your qn is related to when does R makes a deep copy of data.frame. try running `tracemem(df)` and `tracemem(data)` right after `df <- data`