# splitting a dataframe into list of data frames by column while keeping index columns and a single variable column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to split a very large dataframe (>30k columns) into a list of one dataframe for each column. The first subset of columns need to be retained along with one of the variables columns

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10, 5, 1), b = rnorm(10, 5, 1), c = rnorm(10, 5, 1), z = rnorm(10, 5, 1), y = rnorm(10, 5, 1), x = rnorm(10, 5, 1))

df2 <- df[,c(1:3, 4)]
df3 <- df[,c(1:3, 5)]
df4 <- df[,c(1:3, 6)]

df_lst <- list(df2, df3, df4)

print(df_lst)

[[1]]
          a        b        c        z
1  4.238476 4.679300 4.130648 4.776896
2  6.188461 5.699747 6.805005 5.368721
3  3.499334 4.898571 5.269526 7.480616
4  3.794947 5.678742 4.665254 4.858043
5  6.147911 4.302304 6.678942 4.568004
6  5.962222 6.097972 4.964567 4.208009
7  4.881732 4.503572 4.851499 5.308722
8  6.182574 3.132828 6.021901 4.269564
9  6.414729 5.848496 4.583004 4.937372
10 4.657626 5.367495 6.346942 5.409236

[[2]]
          a        b        c        y
1  4.238476 4.679300 4.130648 5.689420
2  6.188461 5.699747 6.805005 5.371570
3  3.499334 4.898571 5.269526 3.489572
4  3.794947 5.678742 4.665254 5.980430
5  6.147911 4.302304 6.678942 5.541403
6  5.962222 6.097972 4.964567 5.899039
7  4.881732 4.503572 4.851499 3.923487
8  6.182574 3.132828 6.021901 3.468816
9  6.414729 5.848496 4.583004 4.050194
10 4.657626 5.367495 6.346942 3.993663

[[3]]
          a        b        c        x
1  4.238476 4.679300 4.130648 2.207792
2  6.188461 5.699747 6.805005 5.182806
3  3.499334 4.898571 5.269526 5.067943
4  3.794947 5.678742 4.665254 4.907648
5  6.147911 4.302304 6.678942 3.811196
6  5.962222 6.097972 4.964567 4.732654
7  4.881732 4.503572 4.851499 4.784362
8  6.182574 3.132828 6.021901 5.278033
9  6.414729 5.848496 4.583004 5.561287
10 4.657626 5.367495 6.346942 4.343982
```

Here columns `a:c` are retained in each of the dataframes in the list whilst the variable columns `z:x` are unique to each dataframes in the list.

Using lapply I can create a list of dataframes for each variable like this

```
core <- colnames(df)[1:which(colnames(df) == 'c')]
vars <- colnames(df)[which(colnames(df) == 'z'):ncol(df)]

vars_lst <- lapply(vars, function(x){df[,x, drop=F]})
```

How can I use the `core` variables to bind them to each of the dataframes in vars_lst?

Comment: Hi! Are you really sure that there is no other way? If there is a really huge data.frame you will create >30k copies of every retained column (a, b, c). I would suggest to look for another approach. Probably dynamic selecting of columns on demand instead?

Comment: yes you are right my approach is going to be very inefficient due to creating huge numbers of dataframes. I will have a think of how to improve it as I work through the  project.

Comment: @asd-tm this doesn't create copies - see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function that will produce the same output as `df_lst`. Better to select the columns you need when you subset rather than do 30k joins.

```r
split_df_by_col <- function(df, index_cols) {
    cols_to_split <- setdiff(names(df), index_cols)
    lapply(cols_to_split, \(col) df[, c(index_cols, col)])
}

split_df_by_col(df, index_cols = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

#### A note on creating copies

Incidentally this will not create 30k copies of the data. R [only copies by value when an object is modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655287/r-deep-vs-shallow-copies-pass-by-reference). The memory address of each column for each element of a list created in this way is the same as it is in the original data frame:

```r
l <- split_df_by_col(df, index_cols = c("a", "b", "c"))
sapply(l, \(df) lobstr::obj_addr(df$a))
# [1] "0x5e04b78" "0x5e04b78" "0x5e04b78"
lobstr::obj_addr(df$a)
# [1] "0x5e04b78"
```

If you start changing the values then of course you cannot store different values in the same memory address:

```r
l[[1]]$a  <- 1
sapply(l, \(df) lobstr::obj_addr(df$a))
# [1] "0x10e06568" "0x5e04b78"  "0x5e04b78"
```

This also applies if you change `df$a`: the memory address of that vector changes, but the multiple references to the original `df$a` in your list remain the same.

Comment: when I apply this to my dataframe which takes up 9.303434 GB of memory, my list of dataframes, df_lst now takes up 223.198 GB. Any idea what is causing this massive increase in size for the list compared to the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Here is nother approach:

```
retained_cols <- c("a", "b", "c")
lapply(names(df)[seq_along(df)][!(names(df)[seq_along(df)] %in% retained_cols)], 
       \(i) (df[, c(retained_cols, i)]))
```

or:

```
lapply(names(df)[names(df)!=retained_cols], 
       \(i) (df[, c(retained_cols, i)]))
```