# memory usage when splitting large dataframe using lapply

Tags: r, dataframe, foreach, lapply, doparallel

I have a large dataframe 54k rows, 38k columns. My goal is to run a simple function, test_func, on this dataframe. `test_func` requires the use of 8 index columns that contain generic information, such as dates and times as well as numeric values. I then have 38k different columns of integer data (0,1) that I want to run test_func() on one after the other and store the results.

I had originally assumed the best approach to do this was to take my large dataframe and split it into a list of dataframes, where each element of the list has a dataframe that contains the index columns plus one of the variable columns to be tested on the current iteration. I thought this was the best approach so as to not have to manipulate the large dataframe on each loop iteration.

The splitting of the large dataframe was achieved via `lapply` using the following code that came from help received in this post ([splitting a dataframe into list of data frames by column while keeping index columns and a single variable column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77913799/splitting-a-dataframe-into-list-of-data-frames-by-column-while-keeping-index-col)).

```
set.seed(123)
    df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10, 5, 1), b = rnorm(10, 5, 1), c = rnorm(10, 5, 1), z = rnorm(10, 5, 1), y = rnorm(10, 5, 1), x = rnorm(10, 5, 1))
    
    split_df_by_col <- function(df, index_cols) {
        cols_to_split <- setdiff(names(df), index_cols)
        lapply(cols_to_split, \(col) cbind(df[, c(index_cols, col)], type = col))
    }
    
    df_lst <- split_df_by_col(df, index_cols = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

However, when I apply this to my dataframe which takes up 9.303434 GB of memory, my list of dataframes, df_lst now takes up 223.198 GB. I then pass df_lst to a `foreach()` function which iterates over each dataframe in the list using parallel processing as follows

```
# set up cluster
ncores <- detectCores(logical = FALSE) - 1
myCluster <- makeCluster(ncores, type = "FORK", outfile="") 
registerDoParallel(myCluster)

 run <- foreach(i = seq_along(df_lst), .errorhandling='pass', %dopar% {
                                flt_dat <- df_lst[[i]]
                                res <- test_function()
                                return(res)
                        }

# shut down cluster
stopCluster(myCluster)
```

Unfortunately this causes R to crash and the run to fail. I know that the run works perfectly on smaller datasets as Ive tested it on dataframes with 5k cols and it works fine.

What is the best approach to this problem?

Comment: I don't understand. A data.frame is already a list of column vectors. I can't imagine any valid reason to split this list. If you need these separate data.frames, just subset once you need them, e.g., `iris[1]`. Don't create all separate data.frames before you need them. That is just wasteful.

Comment: I have updated my question to elaborate more on what I am doing. Perhaps you are right, I dont need to make the list. My understanding was that I needed to pass a list to the foreach() function I am using. I also didn't want to carry out manipulations using my test_function() on the dataframe with 38k cols - rather each one in the df_lst has only 8 cols

Comment: Why can't you just do `foreach(x = yourdataframe[-indexcolumns])`? `x` will just be a vector and you can combine it with other data into a data.frame within the parallel loop.

Comment: The real answer is probably to reshape your data.frame to long format. Depending on the function using this input (and how it could be improved), massive performance boosts might be possible without any R-level parallelization.

Comment: I have tried using pivot_longer() to create a long df where each column is appended but then this becomes too large for R as its 38k (cols) * 54k (rows)

Comment: Elaborate on `test_function`.

Comment: it runs a for loop that iterates over rows of flt_dat. It does some basic calculations using if() else() commands and stores the output in two dataframes which are returned as a list by the test_function()

Comment: @Roland in x = yourdataframe[-indexcolumns] what is this doing? If its is removing the indexcols why not use [ , -indexcols]? If I remove the index cols I am still left with a dataframe which has >30k columns. Im sure Im missing something in your answer but be great if you can elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it's worth a note. This is a follow-up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77913799/splitting-a-dataframe-into-list-of-data-frames-by-column-while-keeping-index-col

Comment: @Friede yes correct. It's part of the same project. What is the most appropriate way to link these posts?

Comment: I think you might consinder spending some time on an explanation of your overall goal. I believe this currently is an *XY problem*: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Friede you are right. I am going to edit this question appropriately with the full picture. Thanks for your suggestion. I was approaching the problem step by step but this isn't helpful.

Comment: Passing lots of data between workers is probably the issue - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74706306/how-do-i-parallelize-this-lapply-function-in-r/74709053#74709053

Comment: Question now edited to give the full picture. Apologies for inefficient posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid unnecessary copies of data.

This should illustrate how you can approach this:

```
library(foreach)

ix <- df[, index_cols]
dat <- df[, !colnames(df) %in% index_cols]

foreach(x = dat, n = names(dat)) %do% {
  cbind(ix, setNames(list(x), n))
}
```

You don't share the function but it might be better to focus on optimizing that function's performance and redesign the whole approach and get rid of the need for a `foreach` loop. If you go that route, you should probably `melt` your data.frame as a first step.

Comment: Thanks. When I run this with the following run <- foreach(x = dat, n = names(dat), .errorhandling='pass') %dopar% { flt_dat <- cbind(ix, setNames(list(x), n)) res <- my_fun(flt_dat) return(res) } it breaks and I get errors "__the_process_has_forked_and_you_cannot_use_this_corefoundation_functionality___you_must_exec__"

Comment: running the same code without initiating parallel processing works just fine. However each of the 37k iterations takes 1 minute so Im looking at about 25 days to complete the loop!

Comment: Can't help you without a minimal reproducible example. Googling the error points to issues on MacOS (which I'm using right now). I don't expect this is related to the approach demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: If your function is slow, it is slow.

Comment: It's strange though because when using the list approach (i.e. split into list of df) parallel processing worked fine with lists of around 5k elements. I guess I'll keep plugging away or try to simplify my function into a minimal example the reproduces the problem. Thanks for your efforts in trying to help.

Comment: Why are you using a fork cluster and not a socket cluster? ["RStudio Inc. recommends against using forked processing when running R from within the RStudio software"](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/parallelly/html/supportsMulticore.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256742/discussion-between-thallyho-and-roland).